# Mis archivos en formato png, jpg y pdf se dañan al cargarlos a mi servidor ftp

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, fileupload, filezilla

Tengo una aplicación hecha en Asp.net c# para subir archivos a mi servidor ftp
El PROBLEMA viene cuando intento visualizar esos archivos, estos aparecen vacíos(Dañados) y no es posible ver su contenido

Este es mi código:

```
if (ftpFileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            string fileName = Server.HtmlEncode(ftpFileUpload.FileName);
            string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);

            if ((extension == ".jpg") || (extension == ".pdf") || (extension == ".png"))
            {

                string filename = "Comprobante"+extension;

                Stream fs = ftpFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

                string filePath = filename;
                File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(filePath), bytes);

                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://Servidor/Carpeta/" + filename);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User", "Pass");

                byte[] fileContents;

                using (StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(filePath)))
                {
                    fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
                }
                request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                txtNombre.Text = "Solo se permiten Archivos con Formato | .png | .jpg | .pdf |";
            }
        }
```

Si me dieran una solución estaré muy agradecido buen día!!!

Comment: Son archivos [binarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.usebinary?view=net-7.0). Intenta con `request.UseBinary = true;`.

Comment: @Sal ya lo intente y sigo sin poder visualizar los archivos